# Compare and remove elements from list

Tags: prolog

So i want to make a program that, given a list and an element, returns only the list until said element appears,like this:

```
propaga( [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)],(1,3),L).
L = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)].
```

Currently i have this:

```
adiciona((X,Y),[],[(X,Y)]).
adiciona((X,Y), [(W,Z)|Tail],[(W,Z)|Tail1]):-
    adiciona((X,Y),Tail,Tail1).

 propaga_aux([X|_], X, [X]).

 propaga_aux([(X,Y)|_], (Z,W), P):-
   (X,Y) = (Z,W), !,
   adiciona((X,Y),[],P).

 propaga_aux([(X,Y)|T], (Z,W), P):-
  (X,Y) \= (Z,W), !,
  adiciona((X,Y),[],P),
  propaga_aux(T, (Z,W), P).
```

Adiciona adds an element to the end of a list.
It keeps returning false, i think the problem is how i use the predicate adiciona but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, i have tried a lot of variations and i can't get this right, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate `adiciona` works correctly.

However note that you don't necessarily need to repeat the term `(A,B)` everywhere. If you put a single variable in place of that it will work the same way, and it will be more generic.

The problem is the other predicate: I would make it this way:

- when you haven't found the matching item yet, the items are copied to the output list recursively;
- when the matching item is found, the output list is composed only of that element, and recursion will stop.

At this point you realize that the predicate `adiciona` is not needed to solve this problem.

Prolog code:

```
propaga([X|Xs], Z, [X|Ys]) :- X \= Z, propaga(Xs, Z, Ys).
propaga([X|_], X, [X]).
```

Test:

```
?- propaga( [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)],(1,3),L).
L = [(1, 1),  (1, 2),  (1, 3)] ;
false.
```

Comment: its not working, i keep getting false...i used trace, and he compares the first element with (1,3), but the it gets to (1,2), fails and returns false